# How to collapse the subcircuits in a QuantumCircuit?

Tags: programming, qiskit

Suppose I have a `QuantumCircuit` object named `FC`, which explicitly contains the identity gate, and convert it into a gate using `.to_instruction()`:

`gate = FC.to_instruction()`

and I use this to create a bigger `QuantumCircuit` object named `circuit`, which looks like this:

[image]

Now, when I iterate over the elements of the `circuit`, using this code:

```
for instruction, qarg, carg in circuit:
    print(instruction)
```

I get this:

```
Instruction(name='gate', num_qubits=3, num_clbits=0, params=[])
Instruction(name='gate', num_qubits=3, num_clbits=0, params=[])
```

However, `gate` itself is made up of its constituent elements, which don't show up in the above list. How do I "collapse" the circuit, so that I can iterate over all the components present in `circuit`, rather than just `gate`? One way you can go about doing this is to transpile the circuit like this:

```
from qiskit import Aer, transpile

simulator = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')
circ = transpile(circ, simulator)
```

and iterate over `circ`, but when I do that, the identity gate does not show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by calling `QuantumCircuit`'s [`decompose()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.decompose) method as follows:

```
for instruction, qarg, carg in circuit.decompose():
    print(instruction)
```

Another option is to add `FC` to your circuit using [`compose`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.compose) method intead of `append`:

```
circuit = circuit.compose(FC, [0, 1, 2])
```

Note that you should use `FC` directly without converting it into a gate.